# Transparent background image over transparent Form

Tags: c#, winforms, background-image, transparent

Well I was doing this setting the TransparencyKey same as BackColor, but doesn't makes totally transparent, here a pic:

[image]

How to make the form totally transparent to set the BackgroundImage a transparent Back-Colored .png?
Hope someone could help me (I've had this doubt for so long)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `TransparencyKey` should be a color on the background image, not a color on the form itself. So you can't set the `TransparencyKey` to the form's `BackColor` since the form is not its own background image.
It's been a very long time I read it but I'll post a reference link as I've found it. It's on MSDN, I believe.